URDF File is not parsed, robot state publisher sees the robot description empty. RCLCPP does not exist in libexec?
After finishing the migration of a project for a simulation of a robot, my first launch file which i will provide later contains the robot state publisher, which I give the the robot description and the urdf path as an argument, i tried multiple variations to this input, but every time it seems like the robot description appears empty. Even though in Gazebo and RVIZ, I can see the robot, and when i provide RVIZ the urdf file of the robot it says "URDF Parsed OK". I do not think there are problems with the URDF itself, i went over it multiple times, and it is also spawned normally when i use spawn entity. I checked and confirmed that the urdf is present in the install directory, so it is accessible. My package.xml and cmakelists also contain all the needed dependencies and installs, I will not provide them so the question is not too long, but i will be happy to do so if someone thinks it is important to look at them.
There is a second error at the top, which has to do with rclcpp, which is a very weird error that i do not understand if someone would take a look at this one as well.
Here is the robot state publisher error:
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [162438]
[INFO] [gzclient --verbose  -2]: process started with pid [162440]
[INFO] [ros2-3]: process started with pid [162443]
[INFO] [ros2-4]: process started with pid [162446]
[INFO] [ros2-5]: process started with pid [162448]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-6]: process started with pid [162450]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-7]: process started with pid [162452]
[INFO] [spawner.py-8]: process started with pid [162454]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-9]: process started with pid [162456]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-10]: process started with pid [162458]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-11]: process started with pid [162460]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-12]: process started with pid [162462]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-13]: process started with pid [162464]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-14]: process started with pid [162466]
[INFO] [move_group-15]: process started with pid [162468]
[robot_state_publisher-13] [FATAL] [1718973488.208546430] [robot_description.robot_state_publisher]: robot_description parameter must not be empty
[robot_state_publisher-13] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[robot_state_publisher-13]   what():  robot_description parameter must not be empty
[robot_state_publisher-7] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-7] Link camera_1_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-7] Link camera_2_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-7] Link camera_3_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-7] Link camera_4_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-7] Link TubeLongitudinalRail had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-7] Link TubeTelescopeCarriage had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-7] Link TubeTelescope had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-7] Link TubeArm had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-7] Link XRayTube had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-7] Link Collimator had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718973488.211273712] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Collimator
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718973488.211397537] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment TubeArm
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718973488.211409853] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment TubeLongitudinalRail
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718973488.211417825] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment TubeTelescope
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718973488.211425122] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment TubeTelescopeCarriage
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718973488.211432186] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment XRayTube
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718973488.211439178] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_1_link
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718973488.211446192] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_2_link
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718973488.211454390] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_3_link
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718973488.211464488] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_4_link
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1718973488.211471915] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[robot_state_publisher-10] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-10] Error:   Error document empty.
[robot_state_publisher-10]          at line 71 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-urdfdom-2.3.3/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
[robot_state_publisher-10] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[robot_state_publisher-10]   what():  Unable to initialize urdf::model from robot description
[robot_state_publisher-9] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-9] Link camera_1_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-9] Link camera_2_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-9] Link camera_3_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-9] Link camera_4_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-9] Link TubeLongitudinalRail had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-9] Link TubeTelescopeCarriage had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-9] Link TubeTelescope had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-9] Link TubeArm had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-9] Link XRayTube had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-9] Link Collimator had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-9] [INFO] [1718973488.216233105] [YSIO.robot_state_publisher]: got segment Collimator
[robot_state_publisher-9] [INFO] [1718973488.216325055] [YSIO.robot_state_publisher]: got segment TubeArm
[robot_state_publisher-9] [INFO] [1718973488.216337846] [YSIO.robot_state_publisher]: got segment TubeLongitudinalRail
[robot_state_publisher-9] [INFO] [1718973488.216346429] [YSIO.robot_state_publisher]: got segment TubeTelescope
[robot_state_publisher-9] [INFO] [1718973488.216356009] [YSIO.robot_state_publisher]: got segment TubeTelescopeCarriage
[robot_state_publisher-9] [INFO] [1718973488.216366988] [YSIO.robot_state_publisher]: got segment XRayTube
[robot_state_publisher-9] [INFO] [1718973488.216376099] [YSIO.robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_1_link
[robot_state_publisher-9] [INFO] [1718973488.216383178] [YSIO.robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_2_link
[robot_state_publisher-9] [INFO] [1718973488.216389813] [YSIO.robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_3_link
[robot_state_publisher-9] [INFO] [1718973488.216396462] [YSIO.robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_4_link
[robot_state_publisher-9] [INFO] [1718973488.216405527] [YSIO.robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[robot_state_publisher-12] [FATAL] [1718973488.215552581] [robot_description.robot_state_publisher]: robot_description parameter must not be empty
[robot_state_publisher-12] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[robot_state_publisher-12]   what():  robot_description parameter must not be empty
[robot_state_publisher-14] [FATAL] [1718973488.220441173] [robot_description.robot_state_publisher]: robot_description parameter must not be empty
[robot_state_publisher-14] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[robot_state_publisher-14]   what():  robot_description parameter must not be empty
[robot_state_publisher-11] [FATAL] [1718973488.236433334] [robot_state_publisher]: robot_description parameter must not be empty
[robot_state_publisher-11] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[robot_state_publisher-11]   what():  robot_description parameter must not be empty

here is my launch file:
import os
import launch
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription, ExecuteProcess
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory



def generate_launch_description():
    paused = LaunchConfiguration('paused', default='false')
    gazebo_gui = LaunchConfiguration('gazebo_gui', default='true')
    urdf_path_str = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_model'), 'urdf', 'mtr.urdf')
    urdf_path = LaunchConfiguration('urdf_path', default=os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_model'), 'urdf', 'mtr.urdf'))

    with open(urdf_path_str, 'r') as infp:
        robot_desc = infp.read()
    
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument('paused', default_value='false'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument('gazebo_gui', default_value='true'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument('urdf_path', default_value=os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_model'), 'urdf', 'mtr.urdf')),

        #Launch Gazebo
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), '/launch/gazebo.launch.py']),
            launch_arguments={
                'world': os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_simulation') , 'worlds' , 'simulation.world'),
                'verbose': 'true',
                'paused': LaunchConfiguration('paused'),
                'gui': LaunchConfiguration('gazebo_gui'),
                'use_sim_time': 'false'
            }.items()
        ), 


        
        #Spawn the room
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['ros2', 'run', 'gazebo_ros', 'spawn_entity.py', '-entity', 'room', '-x', '0', '-y', '0.8475', '-z', '1.4', '-file',
                 os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_simulation'), 'models', 'Scan_Room', 'model.sdf')],
            output='screen'
        ), 

        #Spawn the bed
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['ros2', 'run', 'gazebo_ros', 'spawn_entity.py', '-entity', 'bed', '-z', '0.375', '-Y', '1.57', '-file', 
                 os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_simulation'), 'models', 'PatientBed', 'model.sdf')],
            output='screen'
        ), 

        #Spawn the robot
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['ros2', 'run', 'gazebo_ros', 'spawn_entity.py', '-entity', 'robot', '-x', '0', '-y', '0', '-z', '0', '-file', urdf_path_str],
            output='screen'
        ), 

        Node(
            package="joint_state_publisher",
            executable="joint_state_publisher",
            name="joint_state_publisher",
        ),
        
        #Run robot state publisher: broadcast the state of the robot to the tf library
        Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_desc}],
            arguments=[urdf_path]
        ), 
 


        #PID parameters 
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_moveit_config'),'launch', 'ros_controllers.launch.py')])
        ), 


        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_moveit_config'),'launch', 'move_group.launch.py')])
        )
    ])

here is the rclcpp weird error:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ros/.ros/log/2024-06-21-14-38-07-550484-ros-162425
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<LaunchService._process_one_event() done, defined at /opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:226> exception=SubstitutionFailure("package 'rclcpp' found at '/opt/ros/foxy', but libexec directory '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/rclcpp' does not exist")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 228, in _process_one_event
    await self.__process_event(next_event)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 248, in __process_event
    visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(entity, self.__context))
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  [Previous line repeated 5 more times]
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 38, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    sub_entities = entity.visit(context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/action.py", line 108, in visit
    return self.execute(context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/node.py", line 453, in execute
    ret = super().execute(context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/actions/execute_process.py", line 823, in execute
    self.__expand_substitutions(context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/actions/execute_process.py", line 668, in __expand_substitutions
    cmd = [perform_substitutions(context, x) for x in self.__cmd]
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/actions/execute_process.py", line 668, in <listcomp>
    cmd = [perform_substitutions(context, x) for x in self.__cmd]
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in perform_substitutions
    return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_context.py", line 232, in perform_substitution
    return substitution.perform(self)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/substitutions/executable_in_package.py", line 79, in perform
    raise SubstitutionFailure(
launch.substitutions.substitution_failure.SubstitutionFailure: package 'rclcpp' found at '/opt/ros/foxy', but libexec directory '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/rclcpp' does not exist

Simplified urdf example:
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="YSIO">

  <!-- Dummy Link -->
  <link name="world"/>
  
  
  <!-- Camera 1 link and joint-->
  <joint name="camera_1_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="-1.63 1.49 2.75" rpy="0 0.4 -0.65"/>
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="camera_1_link"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="camera_1_link">
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ysio_model/urdf/model/mesh_file_name.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://ysio_model/urdf/model/mesh_file_name.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>
  
  <!-- i HAVE 4 CAMERAS SO THIS STEP IS DONE 4 TIMES --> 
  
  <!--LINKS--> 
  <link name="TubeLongitudinalRail">
      <visual>
          <origin xyz="-2.5 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
          <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://ysio_model/urdf/model/mesh_file_name.dae" />
          </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin
          xyz="0 0 0"
          rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://ysio_model/urdf/model/mesh_file_name.dae" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <origin
          xyz="0.146130721310519 0.177524818788745 0.321556520254575"
          rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass
          value="16.8138613426866" />
        <inertia
          ixx="0.328029135444028"
          ixy="1.06114732499643E-17"
          ixz="-2.31262379624369E-17"
          iyy="0.347642852033873"
          iyz="0.0231959649530333"
          izz="0.257183544559524" />
      </inertial>

  </link>
  
  <!-- OTHER LINKS ARE DONE THE SAME WAY --> 
  
  <!-- YSIO Joints -->
  <joint name="fixed" type="prismatic">
    <origin xyz="0.305 -0.305 2.9" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="TubeLongitudinalRail"/>
    <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"/>
    <limit lower="-2" upper="1.63" effort="10.0" velocity="0.4"/>
  </joint>

 <!--OTHER JOINTS ARE DOE BETWEEN EACH TWO LINKS--> 
 
   <!--Gazebo links and namespace properties-->
  <gazebo reference="TubeArm">
      <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="TubeTelescope">
      <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="XRayTube">
      <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="Collimator">
      <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/YSIO</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
 

  <!-- CAMERA PLUGINS -->
  <!-- camera 1-->
 <gazebo reference="camera_1_link">
  <sensor type="depth" name="camera1">
    <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
    <camera name="head">
      <horizontal_fov>1.0472</horizontal_fov>
      <image>
        <width>1280</width>
        <height>720</height>
        <format>R8G8B8</format>
      </image>
      <clip>
        <near>0.02</near>
        <far>300</far>
      </clip>
      <noise>
        <type>gaussian</type>
        <mean>0.0</mean>
        <stddev>0.007</stddev>
      </noise>
    </camera>
    <plugin name="camera_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
      <ros>
        <namespace>/</namespace>
        <argument>depth_camera</argument>
      </ros>
      <depth_camera>
        <baseline>0.2</baseline>
        <always_on>true</always_on>
        <update_rate>0.0</update_rate>
        <camera_name>camera_1_ir</camera_name>
        <image_topic_name>/camera_1/camera/color/image_raw</image_topic_name>
        <camera_info_topic_name>/camera_1/camera/color/camera_info</camera_info_topic_name>
        <depth_image_topic_name>/camera_1/camera/depth/image_raw</depth_image_topic_name>
        <depth_image_camera_info_topic_name>/camera_1/camera/depth/camera_info</depth_image_camera_info_topic_name>
        <point_cloud_topic_name>/camera_1/camera/depth/points</point_cloud_topic_name>
        <frame_name>camera_1_link</frame_name>
        <point_cloud_cutoff>0.6</point_cloud_cutoff>
        <point_cloud_cutoff_max>8.0</point_cloud_cutoff_max>
        <distortion_k1>0</distortion_k1>
        <distortion_k2>0</distortion_k2>
        <distortion_k3>0</distortion_k3>
        <distortion_t1>0</distortion_t1>
        <distortion_t2>0</distortion_t2>
        <cx_prime>0</cx_prime>
        <cx>0</cx>
        <cy>0</cy>
        <focal_length>0</focal_length>
        <hack_baseline>0</hack_baseline>
      </depth_camera>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>


<!-- AND THEN SOME TRANSMISSION DEFINITIONS-->

Thank you very much <3

Error:   Error document empty.
[robot_state_publisher-10]          at line 71 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-urdfdom-2.3.3/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
[robot_state_publisher-10] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[robot_state_publisher-10]   what():  Unable to initialize urdf::model from robot description

Leads me to believe that the way you're passing the URDF (i.e., reading the urdf file and passing it as a string) is bugging. Can you try using xacro instead?
robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': launch.substitutions.Command(['xacro ', urdf_path_str])}],
        emulate_tty=True
    )


I used it, I am recieving the same errors from it, saying that "robot descripton must not be empty" but I am not sure anymore which description it is refering to. because the path to the file that i am providing is not empty

Can you share your URDF, please? A minimum reproducible example would suffice. NOTE: For any custom meshes, please replace them with basic shapes - this makes it simpler to check :)

I added it at the end of the question, for the meshed, i just showed how i do the find of the mesh path, i tried using share/package-name in the mesh path, but also did not work, I am still not sure when it says that the robot description parameter is empty, does it mean the whole urdf file cannot be found or some stuff inside the urdf file is missing!! @ssarkar

The part of the URDF you have uploaded looks good to me. One way to debug this is by printing the robot_description parameter(the urdf you're trying to load), before calling it on the robot_state_publisher node. This should give you further information. You can also try to check your URDF using xacro <urdf-file-path>

When i use xacro in terminal, the file is printed without any errors, i also used check_urdf and it gave no errors. Do you think that upgrading my ros environment could help? I am currently using ROS Foxy, but I was planning on upgrading to humble anyway

It is definitely worth updating to Humble at least, if not the latest LTS release.
